# Lock a range of data for a chart

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, charts

I would like some information about how to fix a range of data for creating a chart which is not affected when we add, edit, or delete columns dynamically.

I can't use :

> Select the range + Insert Table + Insert chart

because it crashes excel with my VBA code in the background.

My data are like this:

[image: Figure 1]

And my chart :

[image: Figure 2]

But when my code is gonna cut a row and paste it somewhere else :

It's moving my selection :

[image: Figure 3]

Could you give me different answers for how to solve or possibly solve this kind of thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with your code? That might give us some more context.

Comment: Hello BigBen. Im using vba on this part only to move down each rows by cutting the data and moving them row-1. Like that the actual data will be on top of the list. The problem is the row added on top is not selected anymore.  You don’t need the code i think. But tell me if you really need it. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I wanted more context on "

    Select the range + Insert Table + Insert chart

because it crashes excel with my VBA code in the background."

Comment: It’s when you select the data and click on insert tab and Insert table. Your graph is supposed to be dynamic when you enter, edit or delete some data manually. But my modifications are done automatically in vba. So This solution that we can find on Internet doesn’t work in my case. My vba code is working like this : I have 10 rows of data. When my database is edited then we cut the rows 1 to 9 that we paste on 2 to 10 like that the first row is free to add the modifcation or the added line. But we lose the chart selection on the new first row. Sorry If I’m not clear but I’m trying. Thank you.